# Server doesn't parse PHP

Tags: php, linux, web-hosting

I am trying to transfer one of my clients website to a new server (Hostgator sheard plan). for some reason the the server doesn't parse the php code. I tried to place the website on my localhost (xxamp) and it works great.
[this is the link to the site](http://www.seveloff.com/lincoln/public_html/)

Other wesites in the same server works great. 
What can cause the problem?

Does this website requires some special requirements?
Any help or lead will be great.
this is a picture of the main  websites main folder. maybe it helps some how...

[image]

Tnx

Comment: How do you know it doesn't parse the php code? What error are you getting? When I had my sites on Hostgator, their tech support was pretty helpful.

Comment: try print `info` of that server by creating a single file with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try hostgator support, though i think that the issue is in the method the site was built. I had to disable the `.htaccess` file in order to activate the `phpinfo()` file. this is a link to the info file http://www.seveloff.com/lincoln/public_html/info.php . how can it help me. may the issue be in the .htacces file? what drives me carzy is that the site woks excellent in my local host...

Comment: Maybe you need to put your php files/entire project inside public_html ? On newer Ubuntu servers this is the webroot.

Comment: I have tried it, but i still get the same result. some of the php code does not paese.